# How to save a camera picture from Phonegap to HTML local storage

Tags: cordova, camera, save, base64

I want to capture and save an image in my phonegap app.I've looked around loads but cant find exactly what i'm looking for. Basically what i want to do is have  a function which will take the image from the camera, and then save it to local Storage, either the image itself or the base 64, it doesn't really matter. What i need is a very quick way of getting the image back again after quitting and reloading the application without any interaction from the user. anyone know how to do this, any help us greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer it from here:

[PhoneGap Camera](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html)

Comment: i have read that page many times but there is no mention of saving photo in localStorage

Comment: what you want to save in localstorage...base64 or image file path?

Comment: how to store base 64 image in local storage?